# How can I compare the public API of two classes on the classpath?

Tags: java, classpath, junit4

In my project, I have a dependency to `org.slf4j-api:1.7.2` and `org.eclipse.equinox:org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty:2.0.100`.

*Someone* in the Jetty team copied the two classes `org.slf4j.Logger` and `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` into their JAR. *Thank you for that*

Now I have `org.slf4j.Logger` **two times on the classpath**. That's not a *huge* problem as long as the public API of them is the same.

How can I write a test that makes sure the public API of the two class files is the same?

**EDIT** Examining the classes with reflection looks like an obvious solution but how do I load them? There are two resources `org/slf4j/Logger.class` available. How do I turn a raw `.class` file into a `java.lang.Class` that I can examine?

`Class.forName()` doesn't work in my case because that would just give me one of the two (and I wouldn't even know which one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `javap` program lists the API of a class file.  You call it like this:

```
javap -classpath [your_classpath] -public org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

This will print a list of public members, but you can also type `javap -help` to see other options.

An alternative would be to write a Java program which uses reflection to list the API of each class, but I think this approach would be easier and does exactly what you need.

Comment: +1 for `javap`. I could start that with `ProcessBuilder`, for example. Is there a way to use the code inside of `javap` without starting a new process? Or is `javap` not written in Java?

Comment: As far as I can see, `javap` is a native executable.  EDIT: removed the rest, I missed a bit of the question.

Comment: Actually, `javap` just loads `tools.jar` but the API in there (`com.sun.tools.javap.Main`) probably isn't stable nor is it available for every VM.

Answer (score 0):

You could you reflection to get the public methods and compare those, by the name and their parameters. It will be pretty messy, but it's ok for a test.

Also if it's just a one time thing you could just browse the sources.